# What is the location of "database.config" in Mongify?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongify

I'm using Mongify to convert a SQL Server database to a Mongo database. I was following the documentation and got lost when they referenced the `database.config` file.

I tried creating it and dropping it into:

```
C:\Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems\mongify-1.2.4
```

But this didn't work when I ran:

```
mongify check database.config
```

Where should I put `database.config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this file to any place of disk and specify path to it in command line as recommended in [README](https://github.com/anlek/mongify/blob/master/README.rdoc).